# AJAX doesn't work in browser when wanting to retrieve data from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

I've been experiencing this weird problem when I want to retrieve data from an URL.

```
 $.ajax({
 url: 'URLHERE',
dataType: 'html',
success: function(data) { //function 2
    var xml = $.parseXML(data)
    $(xml).find('StopLocation').each(function() //function 3 
{
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var x = $(this).attr('x');
    alert(name);
    alert(x);

});   //function 3 end } //function 2 end       }); //ajax end
```

This does work in Dreamweaver, but not in browser. I've been reading that it could be because AJAX doesn't work on cross domain on browsers. Is this true? Also read that I could change dataType to 'jsonp' - but this doesn't even work in dreamweaver.

Any ideas what could be wrong? Or should I use a whole other thing than AJAX for this problem?

This is a mobile app in PhoneGap, so I am also using jquery.

Comment: you cannot ajax call to any other server...its a huge security risk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i think is possible, as you use PhoneGap. You can test it with IE (not other browsers)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "url", true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
         var text = xhr.responseText;
         alert(text);
         }
            }
        xhr.send();
```

Hope this works, it does for me at least.
after this you can parse to xml.... and continue your work as you intended.

Comment: This actually works on phone too! Not on chrome or firefox though. Wonder if this will give me problems later. But it works for now!

Answer (score 3):

You read correctly, this is cross-scripting vulnerability prevention at work. You can use JSONP to get around it, but JSONP is not JSON - syntax is slightly different, so the server you're contacting has to send you the data in JSONP format. If you're expecting JSONP and receiving JSON, no wonder it's not working anywhere. If you're expecting JSONP and receiving XML, that's like apples and Toyotas.

Comment: Or the server has to have previously setup cross origin resource sharing patterns.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Good point. In any case, unless the server supports such usage (whether via JSONP or CORS), you're screwed for clientside access.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the quick answer. [LINK HERE TO XML](http://konkurrence.rejseplanen.dk/bin/rest.exe/location?input=Odensest) as you can see here, it just seems like an ordinary XML. What's the best way to retrieve that?

Comment: The easiest way is to pass the request through your server. Basically, curl and dump.

Comment: And what if I want to retrieve clientside without a server?

Comment: Then you convince rejseplanen to allow you access, or implement JSONP API. Easy-peasy.

Comment: Actually, there's another way you can do it. You're not doing a real web application, you're making a PhoneGap application, right? You can always make a PhoneGap extension and write the HTTP call in ObjC/Java. Those are not restricted by same site policy, since they are not executing in a context of a web page. In native code, you can do whatever the hell you want.

Comment: I've just heard that using native code in phonegap is not a good idea. It will be the solution if i can't solve it in another way.